# Move existing SwiftUI app to the new Xcode 12 SwiftUI App Live Cycle

Tags: xcode, swiftui

is there a automatic way to move an existing SwiftUI app to the new Xcode 12 SwiftUI App Live Cycle?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Nope, but I did it and it is very very easy. It is just to move your AppDelegate methods to the new App struct and make some changes in dataflow.

I experienced some performance boost after change the model, but I don't know if it is real or macOS Big Sur issues.

Comment: So you created a whole new project or just used the old one and generated the workflow .swift file by your own?

Comment: I had a big app with old AppDelegate. I just created a new `@main struct MyApp: App`, then I moved inside the viewcontext (Core Data) and made some changes in toolbar/menus, less than 1/2 day. And I sent to the trash my AppDelegate. It is important also to remove the references to the old AppDelegate (if you had) and replace them by another one (it will depends on your app model).